# Output an infinitely proportional sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, open-ended-function

In this challenge, an *infinitely proportional sequence* is defined as a infinite sequence of positive integers such that:

- All positive integers are contained infinitely many times within the sequence.
- As more and more terms are added to the sequence, for all positive integers \$n\$, the ratio of the number of \$n\$s to the number of \$n+1\$s in the sequence must grow arbitrarily large.

An example of such a sequence is the following function taking an index and returning a value:

$$
S(n)=\begin{cases}S(\sqrt{n})+1 & n \text{ is perfect square > 1} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

This results in a sequence `[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 ...`, and it's fairly easy to see why this list satisfies the given properties. The first 4 occurs at index \$2^8 = 256\$, the first 5 at index \$2^{16} = 65536\$, and so on, with each positive integer occuring infinitely many more times than the previous.

An example of an invalid sequence is this:

$$
S(n)=\begin{cases}S(\frac{n}{2})+1 & n \text{ is even} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

This sequence goes `[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, ...]`, and while it does contain every positive integer infinitely many times, and contains each positive integer more than the previous, it does not contain each integer infinitely many more than the previous. In the limiting case, the sequence contains twice as many 1s as 2s, twice as many 2s as 3s, and so on.

Your challenge is to output any infinitely proportional sequence. Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply - you may output as a function that takes \$n\$ and outputs the \$n\$th or first \$n\$ terms, or output an infinite sequence in some form. You may use 0-indexing, 1-indexing or 2-indexing (taking the first term as f(2))

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Comment: An interesting variant of this would be to have the ratio grow arbitrarily *small*.

Comment: Why not just allow any n-indexing(=allow a finite amount of failure)?

Comment: @l4m2 0-indexing and 1-indexing are standard, and I've decided to allow 2-indexing for this challenge because of the n=1 edgecase in most approaches.

Comment: Maybe 3-indexing?

Comment: If every integer occurs infinitely many times, than all integers occur the same number of times. None occurs more often than the rest.

Comment: @PurpleP No. This question specifically uses a definition of proportionality used in number theory, which makes sense and can be a value other than 1 even when both occurs infinitely often.

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Óθ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wQZDAwNXPzt7JQVdOwUlez-7paUlaboWSw5PPrdjSXFScvFCHYjIggUQGgA)

Returns the exponent of the largest prime factor of \$n\$.

### Proof of correctness

Let's look at the ratio between the number of values which return \$k\$ and the number which return \$k + 1\$. For each number which gives \$k+1\$, with greater prime factor \$p_m\$, we can create \$m-1\$ new numbers, by dividing by \$p_m\$ and multiplying by \$p_i\$ for \$i < m\$. However, some numbers are generated multiple times, but it's bounded by their number of distinct prime divisors. If we look at numbers up to \$n\$, that's bounded by \$O(\frac{\log(n)}{\log\log(n)})\$. Therefore we have \$\sum_{p_m} \frac{(m-1)\log\log(n)}{\log(n)} \Psi(\frac n{p_m^{k+1}}, p_m-1) \leq \sum_{p_m} \Psi(\frac n{p_m^k}, p_m-1)\$. We want to show that for every \$N\$, for large enough \$n\$, we have \$ N \sum_{p_m} \Psi(\frac n{p_m^{k+1}}, p_m-1) \leq \sum_{p_m} \frac{(m-1)\log\log(n)}{\log(n)} \Psi(\frac n{p_m^{k+1}}, p_m-1)\$. We'll split it at \$m = 2N \log(n)\$. From theorem 1.4 in [Integers without large prime factors](http://www.numdam.org/item/JTNB_1993__5_2_411_0.pdf), we have \$\Psi(n, p_m) = n^{O_N(\frac 1{\log\log n})}\$. The inequality is trivial for \$m > 2N \log(n)\$, and because \$\sum_{p_m} \Psi(\frac n{p_m^{k+1}}, p_m-1) = \Omega(\frac{n^{k+1}}{\log(n)})\$ grows faster than \$n^{O_N(\frac 1{\log\log n})}\$ the fact that we used \$2N\$ balances the terms we split out.

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes, thanks to @GregMartin

```
Ó¿
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wQZDAwNXPzt7JQVdOwUlez-7paUlaboWSw5PPrR_SXFScvFCHYjIggUQGgA)

Returns the gcd of the prime exponents, which is the largest \$k\$ such that \$n\$ is a \$k\$-th power.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: An integer is "\$k\$-powerful" (or "\$k\$-full") if all of the exponents in its prime-power factorization are at least \$k\$; we can call an integer "exactly \$k\$-powerful" if it is \$k\$-powerful but not \$(k+1)\$-powerful. It's a 1934 theorem of Erdős and Szekeres that the number of \$k\$-powerful integers up to \$x\$ is asymptotic to a constant times \$x^{1/k}\$, which implies the same result for exactly \$k\$-powerful integers. This argument justifies the correctness of this answer.

Comment: By the way, if the *minimum* of the list can be changed to the *gcd* of the list with another character, then the integers yielding an output of \$k\$ are exactly the \$k\$th powers (that aren't higher powers), which simplifies the proof of correctness substantially.

Comment: @GregMartin I don't see how the result on \$k\$-powerful integers helps, because a lower bound isn't hard regardless, and this doesn't directly apply to an upper bound, because \$18 = 2 \cdot 3^2 \$ still returns 2, for example.

Comment: Sorry—I misread the function as returning the *smallest* prime exponent, which is a valid answer to the challenge and to which my argument applies.

Comment: For every \$k\ge2\$, the density of those integers for which the *largest* prime-power exponent equals \$k\$ is precisely \$\frac1{\zeta(k+1)} - \frac1{\zeta(k)}\$, where \$\zeta\$ is the Riemann zeta function. In particular, all of these sets have positive density, and so the largest-prime-exponent function is not infinitely proportional.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, I'm aware (for example take an odd squarefree number and multiply it by 4, which gives a lower bound), but this isn't what I'm doing - I'm looking at the exponent of the largest prime factor, not the largest exponent.

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry about that, I fixed it. Is it better now?

Comment: @CommandMaster I think so :-)

Comment: Got it, sorry for constantly misreading :}

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 10 bytes

```
nM l<gr<bi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FN3czcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmpWVZ16Jrh2QWFpakqZrsSbNNs9XIccmvcgmKRMitDU3MTPPNjdeoaBIJc0m2lBPz9DAIBYit2ABhAYA)

### Explanation

- `bi` convert the input to binary
- `gr` group equal elements
- `nM l` length of the shortest group

This finds the shortest run of equal elements in the binary expansion of the input.

### Proof

I will provide a proof that the proportion of 1s approaches 1. That is \$P(f(x)=1)=1\$ This argument can be repurposed to show that for any number the proportion relative to numbers greater than or equal to it approaches 1. That is \$P(f(x)=n\mid f(x)\geq n)=1\$.

Let's consider the two least significant bits of a number \$x\$. If they are `10` or `01` then \$f(x)=1\$.

The two other options `11` and `00` may be any value. This means that at least half of all numbers give 1.

Now in the general case, let us treat the case where the least significant \$2n\$ bits do not rule out values other than 1. Considering the least significant \$2n+2\$ bits. A fourth of all cases of begin with `010` or `101` and thus \$f(x)=1\$. So 3/4 of all cases have the *possibility* of being something other than 1.

We can use recursion to then derive the following formula:

\$
P(f(x)\neq 1) \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac34\right)^n
\$

We can take the limit:

\$
\displaystyle P(f(x)\neq 1)\leq\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n=0
\$

So the probability of getting a 1 converges to 1.

### Reflection

There are a couple of things that would be nice here.

- There is `sss` which gives the shortest continuous substring satisfying a predicate, and `sSn` which gives the *maximal* substrings satisfying a predicate. Here it would have been useful to have a function which gives the shortest maximal substring satisfying a predicate.
- It might be nice to have a version of `gr` which just gives the lengths of the groups. It's not uncommon to care only about group lengths and not their contents.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 36 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to l4m2, Command Master and xnor*

```python
f=lambda n:-n&n<n or-~f(len(bin(n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3VdJscxJzk1ISFfKsdPPU8mzyFPKLdOvSNHJS8zSSMvM08jQ1NaFqlQqKMvNKNKLTNDI10_KLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM1DHWMTM01Y6EqYaYDAA)

**[39 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31dNscxJzk1ISFfKs8tTydA0T81IUDPOLdOvSNHJS8zSSMvM08jQ1NaHKlQqKMvNKNKLTNDI10_KLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM1DHWMTM01Y6EqYRYAAA) if using `True` as `1` is not allowed:**

```python
f=lambda n:n&n-1and 1or-~f(len(bin(n)))
```

Similar to example but with logarithm base 2 instead of square root.

*I known that `len(bin(n))` is not exactly the logarithm, but it does not make a difference for the purpose of this challenge*

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 36 bytes

*suggested by Wheat Wizard*

```python
lambda n:len(min(bin(n).split("1")))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3VXISc5NSEhXyrHJS8zRyM_M0koA4T1OvuCAns0RDyVBJU1MTqla5oCgzr0QjOk0jUzMtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VcNQx9DAyFgzFqp0wQIIDQA)

Comment: Python, 41 bytes: [`f=lambda n:1if-n&n<n else-~f(len(bin(n)))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3NdNscxJzk1ISFfKsDDPTdPPU8mzyFFJzilN169I0clLzNJIy8zTyNDU1oRqUCooy80o0otM0MjXT8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzUMdYxMzTVjoSphVgAA)

Comment: 40 bytes if you take off the `f=`

Comment: @Jakav How? `f` is used in `f(len(bin(n)))`

Comment: Python, 41 bytes: [`f=lambda n:1if n&n-1else f(len(bin(n)))+1`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3NdNscxJzk1ISFfKsDDPTFPLU8nQNU3OKUxXSNHJS8zSSMvM08jQ1NbUNoRqUCooy80o0otM0MjXT8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzUMdYxMzTVjNSEqYVYAAA), and combining with @l4m2's answer: Python, 39 bytes: [`f=lambda n:n&n-1and 1or-~f(len(bin(n)))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31dNscxJzk1ISFfKs8tTydA0T81IUDPOLdOvSNHJS8zSSMvM08jQ1NaHKlQqKMvNKNKLTNDI10_KLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM1DHWMTM01Y6EqYRYAAA)

Comment: Python, 36 bytes: [`lambda n:len(min(bin(n).split("1")))`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31dJscxJzk1ISFfKsclLzNHIz8zSSgDhPU6-4ICezREPJUElTUxOqWrmgKDOvRCM6TSNTMy2_SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1DH0MDIWDMWqhRmAQA) Implements a function similar to the one in my hgl answer.

Comment: `f=lambda n:-n&n<n or-~f(len(bin(n)))` works if you buy using True for 1

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊞υ¹Ｗ›θΣυ«≧⁻Συθ⊞υ×⌈υＬυ»Ｉ⊕ΣＥυ›θΣ✂υκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7NCsIwDAfws32KHlOYsJ13Eg8ycDKcL1BrWIttnf1QQXz2usp2MaeQf/glQnInblyn1NgxhkM0Z3RwZzXpopcQC1pN/VMqjRR2DnnIcUH7aCAyxuibrFo@brxXgz2qQQZolY1@2ShotlYLdlIGPbT8pcwc79EOQf6smnxI55QNsOU@QGOFQ4M24AUyNp3JxN8TvVYC8/zK5qpTqsqyTOuH/gI) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th term. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `1` `1` as the first term of the sequence.

```
Ｗ›θΣυ«
```

While more terms are needed, ...

```
≧⁻Συθ
```

... account for previous terms, and...

```
⊞υ×⌈υＬυ
```

generate a new set of terms.

```
»Ｉ⊕ΣＥυ›θΣ✂υκ
```

Calculate the resulting term.

The result is the following sequence:

```
1
1 2
1 1 2 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4
1 (24 times) 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 5
1 (120 times) 2 (24 times) 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 6
1 (720 times) 2 (120 times) ...
```

Within each group, the number of times `m-1` appears more than `m` is more than the number of times `m-1` appeared more than `n` in the previous group.

Comment: Interestingly, I believe if each group were reversed, it would not count as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 32 bytes

```r
f=\(n,i=n^.5)`if`(i%%1,1,f(i)+1)
```

Uses the sequence from the question (2-indexed).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3FdJsYzTydDJt8-L0TDUTMtMSNDJVVQ11DHXSNDI1tQ01oerU0jSMTM00uYpTS_wSc1OLNYoTCwpyKjWMrAwNgGo1dcAMqOoFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 27 bytes

```javascript
S=n=>++n**.5%1?1:S(n**.5)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchRCoAgDADQ0wSbq2Af/STaITxBlMYiXFh0faP@Hm@fn/laipx3l3WNtQaXnSfKxvRDwxOPAX4jcU1aQBxbSyQoCQIIesZF86VH7A/dQNovsb4)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

```c
i;f(n){i=sqrt(n);n=i*i-n||1/n?:f(i)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDbTsMwDH3fV1iVJiVto9FNPEAoPCC@gvahSpMRsWUjiURF118nuFeYRORY9rF95GPB9kKEoLkihrY6dx/WY8RNrmPNzOWSbczTvSKaJhnvgjYejpU2hEK7Anw9IJuzFF7WryXk0GYpjLadg3/T0XYdH2jEW2Vj9FK8S4s80DNFRfOyLZq7Z/y3UQp/8100TaqTBdJvoU0tGxy74VP4AE5/yZMi8350MwHxgnBIkqF71jNr8sg00iSQ8auSw5Iinl6jEtHlEMNk@dtwttiiSLSugT0C@rUrDCryKbh0kY0UObhyIu5WXfgW6lDtXWCfgR2OPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>64</del> 63 bytes

A port of [@pajonk's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/268808/110802) in Scala.

Saved 1 byte(s) thanks to the comment of @pajonk

---

```scala
def f(n:Double):Int={val i=math.sqrt(n);if(i%1>0)1 else f(i)+1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BTsMwEEX3PcWoEpItlLSGDUqVoCI2SHSFWFUVclKnNXLGwZ5Ao6onYdMNbLgD9-ht6oSwmvme_7-eP799IY28_lmOI7Qf0uF4dZrZ_FUVBAupEfYjgLUqoQqCSbfxCcydk-3yiZzGzYon8IyaIO2d8NVQGd2cbrtIyTC5t01uFE8ekNL9uzSg00rSNvZvjhjymS6ZvhDZlAtQxquQ0fxSHIaa39AIkwnM69q0QNtwb7AgbRHI9hqbKlfOQ-lsBVfdq5gKkLiGOuBR73HKN4Z8hwcdwqADMvtP8LiSNUNIM0CIsg49JjvA87AuZN3n-1aDbOgIl0ftKfbW0V3Ldmm2i18E58F7GA2_OB7_5hk)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BTsMwEEX3PcWoEpItlLSGDUqVoCI2SHSFWFUVclKnNXLGwZ5Ao6onYdMNbLgD9-ht6oSwmvme_7-eP799IY28_lmOI7Qf0uF4dZrZ_FUVBAupEfYjgLUqoQqCSbfxCcydk-3yiZzGzYon8IyaIO2d8NVQGd2cbrtIyTC5t01uFE8ekNL9uzSg00rSNvZvjhjymS6ZvhDZlAtQxquQ0fxSHIaa39AIkwnM69q0QNtwb7AgbRHI9hqbKlfOQ-lsBVfdq5gKkLiGOuBR73HKN4Z8hwcdwqADMvtP8LiSNUNIM0CIsg49JjvA87AuZN3n-1aDbOgIl0ftKfbW0V3Ldmm2i18E58F7GA2_OB7_5hk), I think (I don't speak Scala).

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 16 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⍵≠⌊⍵:0⋄1+∇⍵*.5}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37Uu/VR54JHPV1AhpXBo@4WQ@1HHe1AjpaeaS0A&f=K0ktLil@1DbBUPtR72YTS64SEF8nWs80Nu3QCjAHAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

-1 byte thanks to att.

A tacit function which takes an integer \$n\geq 2\$ on the right and outputs the \$n\$th term in the sequence in the question.

```
{⍵≠⌊⍵:0⋄1+∇⍵*.5}­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
   ⌊⍵             ⍝ floor ‎⁡input
 0≠               ⍝ ‎⁢not input
 ⍵≠⌊⍵:            ⍝ ‎⁣If input is non-integer:
      0           ⍝ ‎⁤    return 0
       ⋄          ⍝ ‎⁢⁡Else:
           ⍵*.5   ⍝ ‎⁢⁢sqrt input
          ∇       ⍝ ‎⁢⁣apply this dfn 
        1+        ⍝ ‎⁢⁤add 1
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: check int with `⍵≠⌊⍵`